# I can't understand "underneath the underpass" in this context

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is from [a news article](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/06/12/us/philadelphia-i95-collapse-fire-monday/index.html) :

> With thousands of tons of steel and concrete on top of where the fire
> was burning, firefighters initially faced a challenge getting to the
> seat of the fire, Philadelphia Fire Department Battalion Chief Derek
> Bowmer said at a news conference Sunday.
>
> “It looked like we had a lot of heat and heavy fire **underneath the
> underpass**,” Bowmer said.

I think "**the underpass**" is the object of preposition "**underneath**" and "**the underpass**" is on the ground in the below photo.

If so, I wonder what "**underneath the underpass**" means in this context.

[image]

Comment: I think it could possibly a little mistake.  It should either be: a fire in the underpass, or underneath the overpass.  Technically, an underpass is the road that passes beneath an overpass.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the statement could have been "underneath the **overpass**" which might have made the meaning more clear to you, however the author is not wrong.  In common usage, the words "underpass" and "overpass" are nigh-synonymous, even though a glance at the words would suggest that they are antonyms.

In truth, in both cases, an "underpass" or "overpass" refers to the **bridge** that crosses over another road.  You might call the bridge an "underpass" if you are standing on top of it, or on the road leading to the top of the bridge. Similarly, you might call the exact same bridge an "overpass" if you are beneath it, or on the road leading to beneath it.  Alternatively, many people just pick one word or the other and use them arbitrarily, or some people might consistently use them in the opposite way as I described above.  It rarely matters or influences comprehension.

Note that in British English (which I do not personally speak) they would call both an "overpass" and an "underpass" a "flyover" instead, which may make more sense to you as a single object has a single name there.

In summation, I could rewrite the sentence as follows:

> It looked like we had a lot of heat and heavy fire underneath the **collapsed sections of bridge that cross over the (lower) road**.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: In BrE I think we would call the upper road an **overpass or a flyover** and the part of  the lower road which is underneath it an **underpass**

Comment: I think in UK English, "underpass" and "overpass" would be technical terms for civil engineers and highway maintenance departments, rather than ones ordinary people use. "Bridge" and "tunnel" would be the more likely common terms for the structure on top and the space below, even if it didn't meet the technical definition of tunnel. But that's by the by.

Comment: @StuartF Thank you very much.